# implement RPC for a GWT widget inside Vaadin

Tags: gwt, vaadin, vaadin7

I am implementing a RPC service inside Vaadin (for a GWT widget). But the problem is when I try to implement it using the normal method we use with GWT. Which is by extending RemoteService. It gives a error after deploying the war file. I am using Maven to build the project and use tomcat as the server. Is there any work around for this Exception.

The Exception is.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet untitled threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1141)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1612)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    at GXTWidgetTest.MyVaadinUI.init(MyVaadinUI.java:24)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:639)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:222)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1402)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:305)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Looks like you're using or at least importing `com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService` from a Vaadin (i.e. server side) class. This is a client-only interface that is not supposed to be used server side.

Comment: What kind of info you mean. thnx for the reply :)

Comment: @geert3, No i am importing com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService into a cilent side interface.

Comment: You're right, this interface is normally also available server side (for pure GWT applications) via `gwt-servlet.jar`. But this jar is not part of normal Vaadin applications. You could try deploying it together with your application, not sure if that will break other Vaadin stuff.

Comment: @geert3, Sorry I had implemented that interface in one of my server side classes by mistake. Thanx for the help. By removing that implementation I was able solved the exception. but now the I cannot get data from the server side. Thanx for the help :)

Comment: Please post a new question for that, providing as much information as possible. Also please accept (i.e. tick the check mark next to the answer that solves your current question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using or at least importing `com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService` from a Vaadin (i.e. server side) class. This is a client-only interface that is not supposed to be used server side.